# Download folders from Directory listing

Tags: download

I am able to access the directory listing of a web-site. I need to download all the files from a specific folder. Is there some application to help me do this? [This](http://www.arthika.net/1234TB/new/) is the site.

**Edit**: The application whose content I need is a web application like :

> www.example.com/ab/cd

The application which gives me the list of files from the server can be anything - either a webapp or a desktop application.

Comment: This question would fit superuser.com better in my opinion

Comment: Depends on whether the application is web or desktop. For example a we b app that sends me a zip file with all the files from url.com/directory/ then I am not sure, if it is directory listing in terms of server usr/blah/blah then yes @bdhar please clarify

Comment: @phwd - edited the question for clarification

Comment: Ok then I agree with @Joe Philllips . This question is about downloading from a server which falls in superuser.com scope not necessarily a non-hosting directory browser checking as in Plesk. In terms of desktop try HTTrack the guys at superuser.com would be better for this.

Comment: should be migrated to superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref: http://blog.incognitech.in/download-files-from-apache-server-listing-directory/

You can use following command:

```
wget --execute="robots = off" --mirror --convert-links --no-parent --wait=5 <website-url>
```

#### Explanation with each options

- `wget`: Simple Command to make CURL request and download remote files to our local machine.
- `--execute="robots = off"`: This will ignore robots.txt file while crawling through pages. It is helpful if you're not getting all of the files.
- `--mirror`: This option will basically mirror the directory structure for the given URL. It's a shortcut for `-N -r -l inf --no-remove-listing` which means:

  - `-N`: don't re-retrieve files unless newer than local
  - `-r`: specify recursive download
  - `-l inf`: maximum recursion depth (inf or 0 for infinite)
  - `--no-remove-listing`: don't remove '.listing' files
- `--convert-links`: make links in downloaded HTML or CSS point to local files
- `--no-parent`: don't ascend to the parent directory
- `--wait=5`: wait 5 seconds between retrievals. So that we don't thrash the server.
- `<website-url>`: This is the website url from where to download the files.

Happy Downloading :smiley: